# Ruby module/enum retrieves odd values

Tags: ruby

Trying to build an *enum* for ruby so I can retrieve *int* values for the corresponding *enum* value.

My module looks like:

```
module DataType
  STRING  = 1,
  NUMBER  = 2,
  BOOLEAN = 3,
  OBJECT  = 4,
  DATA    = 5,
  FILE    = 6,
  DATE    = 7,
  ARRAY   = 8
end
```

If I call this with any value other than String,

```
DataType::Number
```

It returns

```
 2... 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
```

But if I call

```
DataType::String
```

It returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

How and why is `DataType::String` returning an array of all the *enum* values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare constant by comma:

```
module DataType
  STRING  = 1,
  NUMBER  = 2,
  ...........
end
```

`DataType::Number` second position in module and return value from second position, you need this instead:

```
module DataType
  STRING  = 1
  NUMBER  = 2
  BOOLEAN = 3
  ..........
end
```

Now `DataType::Number` return `2`. and return all:

```
=> DataType.constants.map { |x| Hash[x, DataType.const_get(x)] }
=> [{:STRING=>1}, {:NUMBER=>2}, {:BOOLEAN=>3}, {:OBJECT=>4}, {:DATA=>5}, {:FILE=>6}, {:DATE=>7}, {:ARRAY=>8}]
```

For help [Module#constants](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-c-constants) and [Module#const_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get).

Comment: This worked. Thank you for the help. I didn't really understand Ruby Modules and so now i checked them out. Makes much more sense.